# how to delete a row from table in derby where ID column increment by 1?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

i have problem with my table and exactly in ID column,
when i insert record>>the ID will increment by 1 automatically,
but the problem **that when i delete old record
 and insert new record  the increment continue counting
 and the ID of new record didn't take the ID of old record by sequence**
;

my delete statment :
`String Q="DELETE  FROM EMPLOYEE ( ID , NAME) WHERE NAME='"+lst1.getSelectedValue()+"'";
            stmt.execute(Q);`

create statment:
      `stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY"
                + " GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)"
                + ",NAME varchar(50),BIRTHDAY varchar(50),BIRTHMONTH varchar(50)"
                + ",BIRTHYEAR varchar(50),SEX varchar(50),DEPARTMENT varchar(50))");}`

insert statment:
`String Query="INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(NAME , BIRTHDAY , BIRTHMONTH , "
              + "BIRTHYEAR , SEX , DEPARTMENT) VALUES('"+txname.getText()+"','"
              + ""+compd.getSelectedItem()+"','"+compm.getSelectedItem()+"','"
              + ""+compy.getSelectedItem()+"','"+composx.getSelectedItem()+"','"
              + ""+txdep.getText()+"')";
      stmt.execute(Query);`
thanks very good firstly for answer and try help

Comment: Why is it important if ID numbers are reused or not? Your ID number should be a unique value, and no two employees should ever get the same ID.

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton  thanks to give help ,when i delete an employee i delete his ID too,so i want to use this ID again .and i didn't want to continue counting ID more and more.if u have an idea help me please.my refard

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that on the application side adopting the strategy of not really deleting the row, but adding a boolean field 'deleted', 0 if not deleted or 1 if deleted.

This in the case you want to avoid holes in the ID sequence.

Otherwise you live with the fact that there will be holes in the ID sequence. What is the problem with that?

By the way, what is the DB you are working with?

I read you comment. The point is that all the DBs append new records at the end of the table. So if you want to reuse IDs you have these possibilities:

1. make a piece of code to check if there is a free ID in the sequence
   and use it in INSERT
2. make a piece of code to save free IDs somewhere and reuse them when you insert.

In other terms: you have to manage IDs directly. The way the DB manages them is:

1. Deleting a record produces a hole that will not be filled automatically
2. Adding a new record increment the last id

Regards

Comment: Thanks my dear Feather,i working on derby ..javaDB.please if u can?...give me some suggest code onhow can i solve it .thanks so much

Comment: Updated answer. Regards

Comment: Thanks my dear i will do it and i hope it success.